# Where to put 'allow_empy_files` in a Django form?

Tags: django

I currently have this form and I want to allow the user to upload empty files but I'm not sure on where to add allow_empty_files.

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Uploaded
        fields = (
            'name',
            'description',
            'file',
            'usertags',
        )
```

**Solution**:

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(allow_empty_file=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Uploaded
        fields = (
            'name',
            'file',
            'description',
            'usertags',
        )
```

Comment: What do you mean with upload empty files? If you upload a file, django doesn't know if its empty.

Comment: It does as it's size is 0B and I get an error that I can't upload an empty file.

Comment: please show me your models.py

Comment: I've solved it. I updated the question with the answer.